# Android studio: error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: android, android-studio-4.1

when I run my application this error occurs and when i open task manager, it show 95-95% of 8GB RAM being used and there are too many process with the name **OpenJDK platform binary**, but sometime application runs without any error.

[image]

Also android studio consumes 4GB of RAM as shown by the task manager.Before the android studio 4.1 update, it was working fine

I reinstalled it 8 times (also deleted all the backfile from window C)
but this error coming again and again